# How to list of all the tables defined for the database when using active record?

Tags: activerecord

How do I get a list of all the tables defined for the database when using active record?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Call [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#tables`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L21).  This method is undocumented in the MySQL adapter, but is documented in the PostgreSQL adapter.  SQLite/SQLite3 also has the method implemented, but undocumented.

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["accounts", "assets", ...]
```

See [`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:21`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L21), as well as the implementations here:

- [`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:412`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb#L412)
- [`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:615`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L615)
- [`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:176`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb#L176)

Comment: The list also includes `schema_migrations` table. Just be aware. Thanks :)

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection  may be deprecated ? https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection  I  don't see  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables listed there.

Answer (score 22):

Based on the two previous answers, you could do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  next if table.match(/\Aschema_migrations\Z/)
  klass = table.singularize.camelize.constantize      
  puts "#{klass.name} has #{klass.count} records"
end
```

to list every model that abstracts a table, with the number of records.

Comment: for the single-line fanatics (without the added security of the regex table match): (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - ['schema_migrations']).map {|t| "#{t.classify} has #{t.classify.constantize.count} records" }

Comment: Why do you use a regex here? Wouldn't "next if table == 'schema_migrations'" work just as well?

Answer (score 18):

> An update for **Rails 5.2**

For Rails 5.2 you can also use `ApplicationRecord` to get an `Array` with your table' names. Just, as imechemi mentioned, be aware that this method will also return **`ar_internal_metadata`** and **`schema_migrations`** in that array.

```
ApplicationRecord.connection.tables
```

Keep in mind that you can remove **`ar_internal_metadata`** and **`schema_migrations`**  from the array by calling:

```
ApplicationRecord.connection.tables - %w[ar_internal_metadata schema_migrations]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there should be a better way, but here is how I solved my problem:

```
Dir["app/models/*.rb"].each do |file_path|
  require file_path # Make sure that the model has been loaded.

  basename  = File.basename(file_path, File.extname(file_path))
  clazz     = basename.camelize.constantize

  clazz.find(:all).each do |rec|
    # Important code here...
  end
end
```

This code assumes that you are following the standard model naming conventions for classes and source code files.

Comment: It also assumes everything in your app/models/ is an active record model

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about active record, but here's a simple query:

select table_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'