# Get all tables from database in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In the admin panel of my app I would like to display all the tables in the database.

The way I am doing this at the moment is getting all the records for each table such as :

```
@users = User.all
@pages = Page.all
etc.
```

The I create a table in my view, adding the table headers manually:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

The I acces all records:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= user.id %></td>
etc..
```

What I would like to do is to get a hash off all tables like this:

```
@DB is { table_name_1: table_object_1, table_name_2: table_object_2}
```

Then in my view I would be able to do something like

```
<% @DB.each do |table| %>
    <table>
        <% @table.each do |record| %>
        <table row>
        <%end%>
    </table>
<%end%>
```

I managed to get the table names using this :

```
@DB = Hash.new
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
      next if table.match(/\Aschema_migrations\Z/)
      next if table.match(/\Aauthentications\Z/)
      klass = table.singularize.camelize.constantize      
      @DB[klass.name] = klass
    end
  end
```

from here: [How to list of all the tables defined for the database when using active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154372/how-to-list-of-all-the-tables-defined-for-the-database-when-using-active-record)

However I get the error that `@DB["User"]` does not have a method `each`

or more precisely..: `undefined method each' for # < Class:0x4ab7af0>`

Comment: You can use `rails_admin`, `active_admin` or my simple library `bareback` for this task, check out https://github.com/nielsbuus/bareback

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind..
Seems I was missing the `.all`

The correct call is : `@DB["User"].all.each`