# Running multiple SQL queries in Rails without closing ActiveRecord.connection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-connection

So I have a rails module called `DbsfnpService`.

Within this, I have a class

```
class DbnsfpAccess < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :dbnsfp
end
```

I then have many methods within `DbsfnpService` similar to this.

```
def get_tables
  sql = "select * from dbnsfp limit 1"
  results = DbnsfpAccess.connection.execute(sql)
  return results
end
```

When I call these methods from another class by including `DbsnfpService`, I would like to only establish one connection to `:dbnsfp` and handle all my queries and then close that connection. I believe how it is now, every method I call that contains `DbsnfpAccess.connection.execute(sql)` is making a separate connection(?). What is the best way to achieve this? Passing in a connection object into these functions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to execute calls on the database without knowing the table names and therefore unable to create rails `ActiveRecord` table models ahead of time.

Instead of executing `sql` you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`
(see this link [How to list of all the tables defined for the database when using active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154372/how-to-list-of-all-the-tables-defined-for-the-database-when-using-active-record))

To use these table names what you will need is to turn `DbnsfpAccess` into an abstract class.

```
class DbnsfpAccess < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :dbnsfp
end
```

Then you can create the models you want to connect to `DbnsfpAccess` like this:

```
class DynamicallyGenratedDbnsfpModel << DbnsfpAccess
```