# Don't Leave Me Table

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, database-migration, rake-task

I am trying to create a rake task that will rollback the database but keep one table. I would guess that the easiest way to do that would be to store that table (maybe in `seeds.rb`) then re-insert it. My ORM is activerecord and my database is postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to do the rollback solely on your development environment, you could do the rollback, edit the migration file to contain only the one table you want to keep, and then re-migrate. (Don't forget you may need to rollback both dev and test environments).

If you're in a team that already has performed this migration, you're probably better off not rolling back. Instead you could create a new migration that undoes all but the one table's changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean drop all tables except one?

You can list Postgres tables via [`tables`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-tables).

Different ways to list tables are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154372/how-to-list-of-all-the-tables-defined-for-the-database-when-using-active-record).

Then you could use [drop_table](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-drop_table) (note `cascade`).