# What is the current (not yet deprecated) way to list tables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I saw [How to list of all the tables defined for the database when using active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154372/how-to-list-of-all-the-tables-defined-for-the-database-when-using-active-record)

it mentioned

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
=> ["accounts", "assets", ...]
```

It works.  Though I struggled to find it in the Rails API docs.. and it seems to be deprecated.

Looking at https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection

it says ( I suppose of connection() )  "Method deprecated or moved"

And it doesn't list anything like .tables as a method.

It said

```
This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v3.2.13) is shown here.

These similar methods exist in v4.2.7:

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool#connection
ActiveRecord::Migration#connection
ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling#connection
ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending#connection
```

I clicked those but I couldn't see the word "tables"  on any of those links.

So I can't see what the non-deprecated way of showing tables is. What is the non-deprecated / not yet deprecated, way?

And if the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` isn't deprecated, then I couldn't find it in the documentation and would like to know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to actually be deprecated, but some refactoring looks to have taken place.

This is now in the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` module, which (as of Rails 5, at least), is included in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter`.

[The `tables` method documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-tables) shows this much the same as before.